# Is there anyway to request feedback/coaching about my activity?

Tags: discussion, support

I consider myself very open to constructive criticism. Is there a way for me to get a pulse on my behavior...other than random chatting. It would be cool to receive feedback about inexperienced mistakes made (i. e. spamming, bullying, etc.). Its possible that I am guilty without knowing it.

Proper etiquette only improves communities...

Forgive is this is already answered.

Comment: I've done something like this with a couple of users via chat, but usually only initiate it if I see the same problems cropping up over and over. And it takes a lot of my time so I'd prefer to only do it if its neccesary

Comment: Yeah, what Wax said. If you really want to do this, open a chat room, post some links to your worse posts, then maybe someone will stop by. But you don't really need it and it does take a lot of time.

Comment: Chatting and/or asking for input on meta (like this), both of which it seems you have done.  Meta is also a great place to ask general etiquette questions since this is where we can discuss how the site runs.  Coaching requests really work best on meta if you have a specific case in mind that you want to know if you could have done something better rather than general questions though (which are likely too broad).

Comment: Thanks everyone...very helpful.